# Cannot read property 'ItemID' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core

model.ts

```
export class ItemDetail {
    ItemID:number;
    ItemName:string;
    ItemPrice:string;
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemDetail } from './item-detail.model';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemDetailService {

  constructor(public fb:FormBuilder, private http:HttpClient) { }
  itemModel:ItemDetail
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/item-detail.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-detail',
  templateUrl: './item-detail.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service:ItemDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
   alert('Clicked');

  }
}
```

component.html

```
<form  #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input type="hidden" name="ItemID" [value]="service.itemModel.ItemID">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="ItemName" #ItemName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.itemModel.ItemName" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Item Name" required minlength="3" maxlength="25">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="ItemPrice" #ItemPrice="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.itemModel.ItemPrice" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Item Price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" required type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid"><i
                class="fas fa-database"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have used template-driven approach, my browser console shows the error "Cannot read property 'ItemID' of undefined".

I am new to Angular and is still learning. These are my files. The error is not showing in the terminal but only in the browser console and the disable property inside the button is not also working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service.itemModel` is undefined, hence acessing `service.itemModel.ItemID` generates this error. You should initialize its value somewhere. You can do it in the service

```
  itemModel: ItemDetail = new ItemDetail();
```

(Although I personally wouldn't keep the form's model in a separate service, but in the component itself).

Comment: Perfect, the error now is gone after initializing the itemModel :)

Answer (score 1):

Use safe navigation operator while binding in Angular, like below mentioned -

```
[value]="service?.itemModel?.ItemID"
```

`?` Safe navigation operator helps to check for falsy, null value while binding and avoid Angular to throw an error.

Comment: This works for one-way bindings like `[value]`, but we also have two-way `[(ngModel)]`s here, can't have the safe navigation operators in those.

Comment: @mbojko true that, I just checked in the form there is two way Data binding too, earlier I see only one day binding so purposed the solution I feel good.

Answer (score 1):

Fort practice purpose i created the stackblitz project and tried what **mbojko** mentioned as a solution, and it seems the error is gone after initializing the itemModel.,

Stackblitz link for the same,

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjxddv)